# Create graphs in Grafana via HTTP API

Tags: grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard with existing graphs and stats.

Now I want to add new graphs automatically to my current dashboard.

As far as I can refer to Grafana's HTTP API documentation, there're only ones to create new dashboard but not graph, stats, ...etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Graph is a part of dashboard. You should create dashboard as one piece, with all panels, rows, graphs, stats and alerts inside. Projects like https://github.com/uber/grafana-dash-gen can help with that.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really promising.